# How to export every n minutes?

Tags: date-and-time

I have a long simulation.
I therefore want to export my results every N minutes.
How can I do that ?

Comment: `AbsoluteTime[]` can measure time. Periodically check if enough time has elapsed. If yes, export and reset the timer.

Comment: @Szabolcs How do I check and how do I initalize ?

Comment: Did you look up `AbsoluteTime[]`? Init: `last = AbsoluteTime[]`, then in a loop:  `If[AbsoluteTime[] > last + 60*5 (* five min *), last = AbsouteTime[]; doExport[]]`

Comment: To just check on the progress, use `Dynamic` stuff. But I do not recommend using it for timing or exporting. Only to check the progress of the simulation.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you very much !!